# Obtener datos de formulario dinamico

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Saludos estoy creando un formulario dinámico con **PHP** de la siguiente manera:

```
 <?php
                          $alergenos = $db->query("SELECT * FROM alergenos WHERE estado=1 ")->fetchAll();
                          $total_pc = 0;
                          foreach ($alergenos as $a) {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-left">
                            <?=$a['nombre']?>
                          </td>
                          <td class="text-center">
                            <input type="radio" name="incorpora_<?=$a['id']?>" id="incorpora_<?=$a['id']?>" value="1" class="incorpora">
                          </td>
                          <td class="text-center">
                            <input type="radio" name="incorpora_<?=$a['id']?>" id="incorpora_<?=$a['id']?>" value="0" class="incorpora">
                          </td>
                          <td class="text-center">
                            <input type="text" name="alergeno_<?=$a['id']?>" id="alergeno_<?=$a['id']?>" class="form-control alergeno" placeholder="Alérgeno" >
                          </td>
                          <td class="text-center">
                            <input type="radio" name="linea_prod_<?=$a['id']?>" id="linea_prod_<?=$a['id']?>" value="1" class="linea">
                          </td>
                          <td class="text-center">
                            <input type="radio" name="linea_prod_<?=$a['id']?>" id="linea_prod_<?=$a['id']?>" value="0" class="linea">
                          </td>
                          <td class="text-center">
                            <input type="radio" name="almacen_<?=$a['id']?>" id="almacen_<?=$a['id']?>" value="1" class="almacen">
                          </td>
                          <td class="text-center">
                            <input type="radio" name="almacen_<?=$a['id']?>" id="almacen_<?=$a['id']?>" value="0" class="almacen">
                          </td>
                          <td class="text-center">
                            <input type="text" name="alergeno_cru_almacen_<?=$a['id']?>" id="alergeno_cru_almacen_<?=$a['id']?>" class="form-control alergenoCruzado" placeholder="tipo alergeno">
                          </td>
                        </tr>
```

El resultado es algo como esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
el mismo lo arma bien dado que cada elemento tiene diferente id:

```
    <tr>
    <td class="text-left">
            Leche y derivados                              
   </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <input name="incorpora_1" id="incorpora_1" value="1" class="incorpora" type="radio">
   </td>
   <td class="text-center">
       <input name="incorpora_1" id="incorpora_1" value="0" class="incorpora" type="radio">
   </td>
   <td class="text-center">
     <input name="alergeno_1" id="alergeno_1" class="form-control alergeno" placeholder="Alérgeno" type="text">
   </td>
   <td class="text-center">
      <input name="linea_prod_1" id="linea_prod_1" value="1" class="linea" type="radio">
   </td>
   <td class="text-center">
      <input name="linea_prod_1" id="linea_prod_1" value="0" class="linea" type="radio">
   </td>
   <td class="text-center">
      <input name="almacen_1" id="almacen_1" value="1" class="almacen" type="radio">
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <input name="almacen_1" id="almacen_1" value="0" class="almacen" type="radio">
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
       <input name="alergeno_cru_almacen_1" id="alergeno_cru_almacen_1" class="form-control alergenoCruzado" placeholder="tipo alergeno" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Lo que he intento:

```
        dataIncorpora = [];
        $('.incorpora').each(function() {
            if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
                element = {}
                element.alergeno_id = $(this).prop("id").split("incorpora_")[1];
                element.respuesta = $(this).val();
                dataIncorpora.push(element);
            }               
        });
```

con lo cual obtengo:

```
0: Object { alergeno_id: "1", respuesta: "1" }
​
1: Object { alergeno_id: "2", respuesta: "0" }
​
2: Object { alergeno_id: "3", respuesta: "1" }
```

al parecer esta bien la manera en la que obtiene los datos solo de los seleccionados.

**Pregunta** es así como se debe trabajar dato que tengo que tambien obtener el resto de datos de cada uno de las preguntas es decir los datos de:

```
incorpora_X
alergeno_X
linea_prod_X
almacen_X
alergeno_cru_almacen_X
```

la idea seria poder obtener algo asi:

```
{
0: 'alergeno':1, 'incorpora':1, 'alergeno':'mi alergeno', 'linea_prod':1, 'almacen':1, 'alergeno_cru_almacem':'mi alergeno cruzado'

1: 'alergeno':2, 'incorpora':1, 'alergeno':'mi alergeno', 'linea_prod':1, 'almacen':1, 'alergeno_cru_almacem':'mi alergeno cruzado'
...
...
}
```

gracias cualquier sugerencia.

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución:

```html
<script>

    var  dataIncorpora = {};
    for (n=0; n<=10;n++) {
      element = {}
      element.alergeno_id = "a"+n;
      element.respuesta = "aa"+n;

      dataIncorpora[n] = element ;
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(dataIncorpora));


</script>
```